# How to solicit more return type information from your Java IDE while processing Java Streams?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, types, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following task:

> Given a comma-separated list of cities (state, city, population) generate a list of states and the most populous city in each state along with the population. The list should be sorted on the name of state.

The `cities.csv` looks like this:

```
New York, New York, 8491079
Los Angeles, California, 3928864
Chicago, Illinois, 2722389
Houston, Texas, 2239558
Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, 1560297
Phoenix, Arizona, 1537058
San Antonio, Texas, 1436697
San Diego, California, 1381069
Dallas, Texas, 1281047
San Jose, California, 1015785
...
```

The expected output looks like this:

```
Alabama, Birmingham [212247]
Alaska, Anchorage [301010]
Arizona, Phoenix [1537058]
Arkansas, Little Rock [197706]
California, Los Angeles [3928864]
...
Texas, Houston [2239558]
```

My attempt (after trial and error and following the *cookbook style* processing of Java 8 streams) looks like this:

```
private static void mostPopulousCityInState() throws IOException {
            Files.lines(Paths.get("cities.csv")).map(City::new)
                    .collect(groupingBy(City::getState, maxBy(Comparator.comparing(City::getPopulation)))) //1
            .entrySet() //2
            .stream()   //3
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey()))
            .forEach(e -> {
                City city = e.getValue().get();
                System.out.println(e.getKey() + ", " + city.getName() + " [" + city.getPopulation() + "]");
            });
}
```

(The class `City` is omitted for brevity, but it has fairly straightforward looking constructor(s) and getters).

This seems alright (although it could be improved). But my questions are more about how to think about Java 8 streams in general:

1. For instance, can I place my cursor on `collect` and do some keyboard shortcut that tells me that it returns a `Map<String, Optional<City>>`? If I did "Navigate to Source" here, then it takes me to generic definition in `Stream.java` which shows `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);` and that is useless in this context. Since the compiler knows about the concrete types at this point in time, is it reasonable to expect that IDE shows them (rather than generic types) to me ?
2. In general, how do you keep track of the return types in pipelines? My current problem is I get lost among the generic return types. Specifically, what would have made it clear to you that the `stream` at `line //3` above is a `Stream` of `Map.Entry<String, Optional<City>>`s?
3. Does it get better with time or do you need a deeper understanding of Java's type system?

Comment: To your (3), one would hope that time (or more precisely, experience) _would_ bring a better understanding of Java's type system....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question, I can't speak to how Eclipse does it, but in IntelliJ, you can hold down a key (Cmd on a Mac) and hover over map or filter function calls to see the types, with generics resolved.

Does eclipse have a refactoring tool that lets you select a subexpression and extract it to a new local variable? That would create a variable that shows you the current type in the pipeline.  I do that sometimes in IntelliJ, when I'm having trouble getting functional types right, and I understand that Eclipse has similar refactoring tools.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a simpler way: you don't need to explicitely sort the map after the group by operation: you can directly use a custom `SortedMap` with [`groupingBy(classifier, mapFactory, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-). In this case, the map factory can be `TreeMap::new`, which will create a `SortedMap` in ascending order of the name of the state.

Note also that [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) returns a Stream that should be closed in a try-with-resources:

> The returned stream encapsulates a `Reader`. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

```
private static void mostPopulousCityInState() throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("cities.csv"))) {
        stream.map(City::new)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                  City::getState,
                  TreeMap::new,
                  Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(City::getPopulation))
              ))
              .forEach((k, v) -> {
                  City city = v.get();
                  System.out.println(k + ", " + city.getName() + " [" + city.getPopulation() + "]");
              });
    }
}
```

With this change, you do not need to have a second Stream pipeline that sorts the entries of the map, which makes your other questions a bit moot.

The IDE issue could be specific IntelliJ (no idea there). I tested with the latest Eclipse IDE (Mars.2), and if I hover over the call to `collect`, it correctly tells me that the return type is `TreeMap<String, Optional<City>>`. You're right that the IDE should be able to show the correct type information.

`entrySet().stream(...)` is clear enough that it returns a Stream of `Map.Entry` element. But to make it easier to understand, you can store the map in a local variable:

```
Map<String, Optional<City>> map = // result of operation
map.entrySet().stream() // ... etc
```